# C# Dictionary : LINQ(select values of different keys) those are enum

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, mapping

I have an Enum and I want to make a mapper with dictionary.

This is my Enum:

```
public enum PrintOrderStatus
{
    Pending = 1,
    Confirmed = 2,
    PreparedForPrint = 3,
    PreparedForDevlivery = 4,
    Delivered = 5,
    Canceled = int.MaxValue,
}
```

and this is my dictionary:

```
var map = new Dictionary<PrintOrderStatus, PrintOrderStatus[]>
{
    { PrintOrderStatus.Pending, new[] { PrintOrderStatus.Canceled, 
                                        PrintOrderStatus.Confirmed } },
    { PrintOrderStatus.Confirmed, new[] { PrintOrderStatus.PreparedForPrint, 
                                          PrintOrderStatus.PreparedForDevlivery } },
    { PrintOrderStatus.PreparedForDevlivery, new[] { PrintOrderStatus.Delivered } },
};
```

Given the current status of my entity, how can I have the values for different keys in an array?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: What do you have and what you want to get? Also I don't see anything that looks like LINQ in your samples.

Comment: I want to select the values of this dictionary when I have the key.using LINQ

Comment: @Ashkan.H I really can't understand where you want to use LINQ when getting value from dictionary

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I was thinking wrong, actually I thought I should use LINQ to get the values of the given key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values associated with a key in a dictionary, you should do:

```
var myStatuses = map[currentStatus];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var posibleStatuses = map[entity.currentStatus]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers address going from the key to the values, but just in case you want to go from the value to the key (the question is not at all clear), try:

```
var keys = map.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(PrintOrderStatus.Canceled))
              .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Note that this will return a list of all keys which have it as a value.  If you just want the first one, use `.First()` instead of `.Select()`.